# Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xdb 0xbb)

Tags: jpeg, photo

Im working with images from a C-astral dron.
It has a Sony 24 megapixel camera and the memory card is an Kingston 64Gb Class 10.
When I copy the Images to my computer I cant open and show me this error.
Can I edit the format of the file to recover the photos?

Comment: Usually JPEG files start with `FF D8`. What happens when you run the `file` command on it (if you have a unix bases OS)? Or can you paste a hexdump of the first 20 - 30 bytes?

Comment: Anyway, your question has nothing to do with programming, so I flagged it as off-topic.

Comment: I understand, but I don't know where to ask this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JPEG stream ALWAYS starts with FF D8. If you have DB BB then it is not JPEG. You may be looking at the raw camera's raw format. I would look in a different place in the storage to find the JPEG files.